# how to prevent "jerking" of tabhost along with keyboard in android?

Tags: android, android-tabhost, android-softkeyboard

When my tabhost moves down along with the soft keyboard they get "jerked". Please give me some solution to remove this "jerking" of tabhost and keyboard.

I have already gone through the below solution:

android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"

but that is not working. Please give me some another solution.

[image]

Comment: Tabs should never be at the bottom in Android!

Comment: Can you give solution if i want to have this at the bottom and not anywhere else ?

Comment: @Aashish if you found any solution pls add here ,it will be helpful